# Inductive definition of a given language

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I'm having some difficulties solving a induction task.

Here is the task i'm working on:

> Give an inductive definition of the given language below:
>
> $\{a^n,b^n\mid n\in\{0,1,\dots\}\}\setminus\{\Lambda,a,b,aa,bb,aaa,bbb\}$

Now, I'm not sure how to start here, but how can I effectively give an inductive definition of the language above?

Comment: Do you mean $n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$?

Comment: I conjecture that both occurrences of $-$ in the question were intended to be $=$.

Comment: @dfeuer i took a screenshot of the statement and updated my post, this is how it looks like. I hope it clarifies your question

Comment: No, that was just a less readable version of the same thing. I believe it now says what it means.

Comment: Dabbish, can you see where to go from the answer I provided? If not, please clarify where you're having trouble.

Comment: Yes, i'm still having trouble solving this. i'm very new to induction. Would be happy if you could give a small explaination on how you can solve this kind of tasks. I can't see where to go from your answer =/

Comment: @dfeuer i would appreciate if you could give some more hints, or show me how you need to think to solve questions like this

Comment: Can you write an inductive definition for addition? How about multiplication? How about for exponentiation? Or the factorial function?

Comment: no, i'm still learning that yet, that's why i'm having som difficulties

Comment: Hmmmhmmmhmmm. Trying to learn too many things at once is dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\underline{\phantom{xxxxxx}}$ and $\underline{\phantom{xxxxxx}}$ are in the language. If $X$ is in the language and $\underline{\phantom{xxxxxx}}$ is true, then $\underline{\phantom{xxxxxx}}$ is also in the language.

**Edit:** A few problems to work up to this:

Find inductive definitions for the following languages:

1. $\{a^n\mid n\in\{0,1,\dots\}\}$
2. $\{a^n\mid n\in\{5,6,\dots\}\}$
3. $\{a^n,b^n\mid n\in \{0,1,\dots\}\}$ (Note that this is shorthand for $\{a^n\mid n\in\{0,1,\dots\}\}\cup\{b^n\mid n\in\{0,1,\dots\}\}$.)

A hint on your problem: can you list the six shortest words in the language you're trying to define inductively?

**Edit:** Answer to warm-up problem 1:

Let $\mathcal L$ be the smallest language $\mathcal L$ such that  $\Lambda\in \mathcal L$, and for each $W\in \mathcal L$,  $Wa\in\mathcal L$.

**Note:** I don't really know what form you're expected to produce, so here are two.

**Full solution 1** (because I am stupid):

Let $\mathcal A$ be the smallest language such that:

1. $aaaa\in\mathcal A$
2. $\forall W\in A: aW\in A$.

Let $\mathcal B$ be the smallest language such that

1. $bbbb\in \mathcal B$
2. $\forall W\in B: bW\in B$.

Then $\mathcal L = A\cup B$.

**Full solution 2:**

$\mathcal L$ is the smallest language such that:

1. $aaaa\in\mathcal L$
2. $bbbb\in\mathcal L$
3. For each $W\in \mathcal L$, if the first symbol in $W$ is $a$, then $aW\in\mathcal L$.
4. For each $W\in \mathcal L$, if the first symbol in $W$ is $b$, then $bW\in\mathcal L$.

Comment: could you please go in more depth so I could understand what to do or how you came out to this solution please?

Comment: I tried solving the question, not sure if it's correct: Basis: X = {Λ}, Induction: If n ∈ X then axb ∈ X

Comment: @Dabbish, much hinges on whether my interpretation of the somewhat peculiar $a^n,b^n$ notation is correct. If it is, then the comma represents "also" rather than concatenation. Usually, concatenation would be represented by $a^nb^n$, and in context I think it particularly likely that the "also" interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Dabbish, why don't you attempt my three warm-up problems?

Comment: I'll try the first one: Basis: 0 ∈ {a^n}, Induction: If n ∈ x then x + 1 ∈ {a^n}. Give me a helping hand if im incorrect please

Comment: I would appreciate if you could give me the answer. I think i would've learned more then actually.

Comment: @Dabbish, I posted a couple full solutions. I don't see how they'll help you more than the examples in your textbook.

Comment: well, the textbook is very confusing that's why im reaching out to a community so maybe there is other ways to learn it easier :)

Comment: @Dabbish, why don't you ask a question about one of the worked examples in your text and tell us what you find confusing about it?